# Lock row_index In HLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of cells that look like:

`=HLOOKUP(D1, Runtime!G1:QR73, 3, FALSE)`

`=HLOOKUP(D1, Runtime!G1:QR73, 4, FALSE)`

`=HLOOKUP(D1, Runtime!G1:QR73, 5, FALSE)`

etc

I use pygsheets to insert a row above row 3 occasionally, and this is causing the formula to increment their row_index by 1 to track the original cell.  Is there a way to keep this value fixed?  I tried using `INDIRECT` but it only works for cell references and doesn't seem to work for this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=HLOOKUP(D1, INDIRECT(“Runtime!G1:QR73”), 3, FALSE)
```

Works?